# spring-boot: ResourceBundle with external messages.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public static MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("file: c:/temp/messages");

        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make spring-boot to use my external messages.properties, messages_en_Us.properties files. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
ResourceBundle [file: c:/temp/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name file: c:/temp/messages, locale en_US
```

Files are there and I have studied such cases and it is stated that this should work in spring-boot, but it doesn't. I have also tried `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and failed the same way. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :

```
messageSource.setBasename("file://c:/temp/messages");
```

**Edit :**

After some tests in comments, it is rather this way of doing which works for the OP :

```
    messageSource.setBasename("file:C:/temp/messages");
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work still, but gives this error: `15:27:23.865  WARN [main] ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource      - Could not parse properties file [messages.properties]
java.net.UnknownHostException: c`

Comment: I think you are not far :)  It looks like `c:` is not recognized.
and with `file://C:/temp/messages` you have the same error?

Comment: With `C:` it is this error: `Could not parse properties file [messages.properties]
java.net.UnknownHostException: C`

Comment: Ok. And with that `file:C:/temp/messages` ? I removed the whitespace from your original value

Comment: great, you are welcome. I told you that you was not far :) But I am surprising that `file://` doesn't work.

Comment: My case is somewhat different from above given case.
Can't find bundle for base name file:./etc/i18n/messages.
etc folder is parallel to src folder.

Comment: Better to use File.separator to keep the code OS independent.
```String propertyFilePath = MessageFormat.format("file:{1}{0}temp{0}{2}", File.separator, homeDirectoryPath, "myProperty");
messageSource.setBasename(propertyFilePath);```